# Timestamp Discrepancy when Retrieving Sequelize PostgreSQL Data in UTC Timezone

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I'm currently encountering an issue with my PostgreSQL setup. In my postgresql.conf, I've configured timezone = 'UTC'. I've also used the commands SET TIME ZONE 'UTC'; and SET timezone TO 'UTC'; in my queries. However, I'm facing an unexpected behavior when querying a table that contains timestamps like 2023-08-25 08:37:02.000.

The problem is that when I retrieve this timestamp using Sequelize, the resulting time is 8 hours behind, specifically becoming 2023-08-25 00:37:02.000. To resolve this, I tried adding the following options to my Sequelize configuration:

`dialectOptions: dbConfig.dialectOptions, timezone: dbConfig.timezone,`

However, these additions did not yield any positive results.

My intention is to ensure that the retrieved timestamps conform to UTC, in line with the PostgreSQL configuration. I've carefully reviewed the postgresql.conf file, and it's indeed set to timezone = 'UTC'.

I'm seeking assistance in understanding why the timestamps are not being retrieved in UTC. Are there any steps or considerations I might be overlooking to ensure accurate timezone handling? Your insights and guidance would be greatly appreciated in helping me address this issue. Thank you in advance!

Reimplementation Error：

```sql
create table test_time(
    alert_time timestamp
);

insert into test_time VALUES('2023-8-26 06:29:40');


select * from test_time;
-- 2023-08-26 06:29:40.000

show timezone; 
-- Asia/Taipei

SET TIME ZONE 'UTC';
SET timezone TO 'UTC'; 

show timezone; 
--UTC
```

```js
const webConfig = require('../config/WebConfig');
const dbConfig = webConfig.dbConfig;
const debug = webConfig.debug;
const DataTypes = require('sequelize');
const {Op} = require('sequelize');
const initModels = require('./init-models');
const sequelize = new DataTypes(dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.CODE, {
  host: dbConfig.HOST,
  port: dbConfig.PORT,
  dialect: dbConfig.dialect,
  logging: debug,
    dialectOptions: {useUTC:false},
});
//initModels are generated by sequelize-auto.
const db = initModels(sequelize);
db.op = Op;
db.sequelize = sequelize;
module.exports = db;
```

I also found it interesting that using findByPk yields the correct time point.

```js
const db = require('../models');
const TestTime = db.test_time;

exports.query = async (obj) => {
  try {
    const testTime = await TestTime.findAndCountAll(obj);
    return testTime;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m', e);
  }
};
```

Comment: Do you use `timestamp with timezone` datatype in DB?

Comment: @Anatoly I am using a timestamp, I am not using a timestamptz, because there are multinational users, I assume that the preset saved date will use utc+0, and add the time of the local user to the front

Comment: Please show a minimal amount of code to make this reproducible.